# The myth of metals

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

The Greeks had a myth of metals. It was the idea that citizens were born of a certain metal according to their place in society. It was a useful lie- something that motivated people to do the right thing for the wrong reasons.

Is there a word for this concept? A heuristic that is wrong but practically useful? There is something kind of similar called thymology, but are there any other words?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This exact concept is from Plato's *Republic* and is typically called the "[Noble Lie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noble_lie)" in the philosophical literature (it seems clear from the *Republic* that Plato invented the myth, it wasn't actually one previously in currency among the ancient Greeks).  It's not clear whether Plato himself considered it a lie rather than just a "creative" way of representing a deeper *Truth*.

The term itself is still in use, but with a narrower scope than what you are seeking, chiefly meaning a fiction promoted as truth to maintain social harmony, with altruistic intentions.

A similar phrase with wider scope (if lesser usage) is **"useful fiction,"** meaning something known to be untrue, but of pragmatic use. I wasn't able to find a definitive citation for this definition, but the term does have some usage, both [within](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fictionalism) and [outside](http://www.usingenglish.com/forum/threads/681-useful-fiction) philosophy, and is easily understood (there is even [a book](http://www.nebraskapress.unl.edu/product/Useful-Fictions,674631.aspx) on the subject).

Comment: It would be even better if there was a single word.

Comment: Why do you want a single word?